# Trying to submit a form on a model in Ionic v4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building a web application with Ionic and Angular, in this page I have the data from an animal, but I also need to add the vaccines that the animal has taken.

I'm using a modal on the save page of the animal. The data in the Save Page can be submited without the vaccines, and is working, but I have a problem trying to submit the vaccines form in the modal.

This is the method that opens the modal in the SavePage:

```js
async saveVacinas(){
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: VacinasPage
      });

      await modal.present();


    }
```

This is the code in the VaccinesPage

```js
export class VacinasPage implements OnInit {
  vacinaForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private modelCtrl: ModalController, private fb: FormBuilder, private vacinaService: VacinaService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm(): void{
    this.vacinaForm = this.fb.group({
      nome: ['',[Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void{
      console.log(this.vacinaForm.value);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>vacinas</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="vacinaForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Teste</ion-label>
      <ion-input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Awesome Input"
        formControlName="nome"
      ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-button type="submit">Click me</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

And when I submit the form, the SavePage refresh, and it can't find the animal's ID in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to pass back the data from the modal to the parent you can do something like this:

So in the parent comp (your SavePage)

```
async saveVacinas(){
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: VacinasPage
      });

      await modal.present();

      modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
      // do something with the data ... 
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

and in your VaccinesPage where you submit, pass the data to the dismiss method:

```
export class VacinasPage implements OnInit {
  vacinaForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController, private fb: FormBuilder, private vacinaService: VacinaService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm(): void{
    this.vacinaForm = this.fb.group({
      nome: ['',[Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void{
      console.log(this.vacinaForm.value);
      this.modalController.dismiss(this.vacinaForm.value);
  }
}
```